# Custom Register Form with Django Rest Auth - Error: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I want to create a custom Signup form with Django Rest Auth and Django Allauth but I'm getting an error `save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I know that this error is related to the function def save(self, request) provided by Django Rest Auth, but I have no clue how I can change it.

What should I do to make it work?

Bellow is the respective code for my user Model and Serializer:

```
# Models.py

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new user"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new super user"""
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'age']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

# serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the users object"""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'name', 'age')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 5}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update a user, setting the password correctly and return it"""
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, **validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user


    def save(self, request):
      # I would say that I need to change the default function

# settings. py

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'user.serializers.UserSerializer'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this fixed I just add the following to my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the users object"""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'name', 'age')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 5}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update a user, setting the password correctly and return it"""
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, **validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'name': self.validated_data.get('name', ''),
            'age': self.validated_data.get('age', ''),
        }

    def save(self, request):
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**self.cleaned_data)

        return user
```